# Can't get ListView background gradient to show

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and I want to have a background gradient that covers the entire listview. I don't want a gradient for each row. All I get is a white background.

Code for gradient in mybg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape>
      <gradient
        android:startColor="#e6e6e6"
        android:endColor="#ffffff"
        android:angle="45" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

My ListView:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvEvents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/mybg"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#ffc0c0c0"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:scrollingCache="true" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the shape , try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:centerColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#404040"
        android:startColor="#404040" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Strange. I use the above what I wrote for other controls and it works but not for a listview. Yours does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try set the row view background to be transparent by using @null.

Comment: Yes. Set android:background as "@null".